# Drupal 6 connect to database

Tags: database, drupal

How does Drupal 6 connect to a database?  I'm use to Drupal 7 having a setting.php file that asked for the database name, the user and the password but Drupal 6 setting.php file is completely different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `$db_url` variable in the settings.php file for the site.

Example

```
// mysql://username[:password]@hostname[:port]/databasename
$db_url = 'mysql://root@localhost/testdrupal';
```

Comment: Wondering how to encode chars in the password field, like %, $, & and #....